# SQL: How to format decimals, including ones less than 1

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

This feels like a REALLY basic question buy I have been looking around for about an hour and have yet to find a straight answer.

I have a decimal number, it represents a weight, I want it rounded and formatted in a way that is considered normal.

```
1.0000 to 1.00
.1900 to 0.19
-.1900 to -0.19
```

Right now I'm getting rid of the trailing zeros by casting as a decimal and rounding them off

```
CAST(TLI_Amount as decimal(18,2))
```

Now heres the kicker. I don't know what version of SQL I'm on, but it must be really old. Old enough that it doesn't recognize FORMAT as a function. Which is pretty much what everyone says to use. That or the leading zero get put in front of everything, but it needs to only be there for numbers < 1

So how can I get my decimals < 1 to read as 0.xx, like any normal human readable number should be.

Comment: The brand of DB would help

Comment: SQL is a language. What database are you working with?

Comment: Sorry, I really dont know. 
It dosn't recognize @@VERSION  or SERVERPROPERTY
and I'm not on any kind of sql studio. I think its called sql-anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Anywhere does support `@@version` so perhaps that's not what you're working on. But if you are, you can look up the documentation on the `str()` function [here](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/81fd8b296ce21014a0aad22fe4cbbfdb.html*loio81fd8b296ce21014a0aad22fe4cbbfdb). In a nutshell:

```
select str( 1.2345, 4, 2 )
   -> 1.23
select str( 0.1234, 4, 2 )
   -> 0.12
select str( -0.1234, 5, 2 )
   -> -0.12
```

There is also a [round](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/81fc81f56ce2101482da803c00ff9ad3.html*loio81fc81f56ce2101482da803c00ff9ad3) function.

Comment: Wow that's incredible, exactly what I was looking for. 
Really baffling to me, why does a function with a name as generic as str() have such a specific function for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about just adding the zero in.  I think SQLAnywhere uses `+` for string concatenation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TLI_Amount < 1 THEN '0' ELSE 1 END) +
        CAST(CAST(TLI_Amount as decimal(18, 2)) as VARCHAR(255))
       )
```

Note:  This assumes that `TLI_Amount` is positive.

Comment: While that would work, and is probably the most elegant way to do it programatically, it seems really silly to do for such a simple formatting requirement. Is there really no native way to format it? Did people not need their numbers formatted back then?

Comment: @SpeedOfRound . . . Formatting is usually done at the application layer.  For instance, I would commonly show the results in an Excel spreadsheet, which offers wide flexibility in formatting values.

Comment: What happens if TLI_Amount is negative? Because that is a valid use case

Comment: Then you need to use `abs()` and a bit more logic.